# Talking to Google APIs from Go hangs

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, google-cloud-run

Following the examples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/spanner/spanner_quickstart/main.go), the code seems to hang making the https connection via gRPC to Google APIs.

The same code works on App Engine Go1.11 and App Engine Flex. Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Use the offical Golang image to create a build artifact.
# This is based on Debian and sets the GOPATH to /go.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/golang
FROM golang:1.12 as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.
WORKDIR /go/src/serverless
COPY . .

# Build the command inside the container.
# (You may fetch or manage dependencies here,
# either manually or with a tool like "godep".)
RUN go get . && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o serverless

# Use a Docker multi-stage build to create a lean production image.
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM alpine

# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /go/src/serverless/serverless /serverless

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["/serverless"]
```

Answer (score 4):

After debugging this a bit, this seems to be related to be related to not having root certificates in the container. Adding the following line after `FROM alpine`

```
# Enable the use of outbound https
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
```

fixes the issue.